# datapicker - range

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con un Date Picker Range Bootstrap, ya que se muestra en la parte de atrás de mi modal, intente con un `z-indez:-1`, pero no veo cambios favorables.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste es mi código:

```js
$(function() {

  var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
  var end = moment();

  function cb(start, end) {
    $('.reportrange span').html(start.format('YYYY MM DD') + ' - ' + end.format('YYYY MM DD'));
  }

  $('.reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
  }, cb);

  cb(start, end);

});
```

```html
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script  src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<div>
  <a type="button" class="hvr-shutter-in-vertical filtradobtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">BOTON</a>
</div>


<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">SELECCIONAR</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="reportrange" name="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%;">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
          <span id="txt"></span> <b class="caret"></b>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1" type="button">Aceptar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deberías añadir el html y css mínimo para reproducir el problema. De ese modo tendrías un [mcve], podríamos ver el error y sería más fácil ayudarte. En la misma pregunta indicas que intentaste solucionarlo cambiando el z-index en CSS, ¿a qué clase?¿por qué -1?

Comment: Podria añadir el modal, pero un modal con configuraciones estandares de boostrap, por eso es que omiti el codigo! pero en un momento lo agrego

Comment: Te decía de ponerlo porque tu intento era bueno (cambiar el z-index), pero parece que el valor no era el adecuado (-1 mandará al fondo del todo) o el elemento seleccionado no era el correcto.

Comment: Tiene sentido tu comentario, ya agregue el modal, gracias por responder @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: He puesto tu código como ejecutable y no parece haber ningún problema: el date picker range se ve por delante del modal y no por detrás. Si sigues viéndolo mal, debes [edit] la pregunta para poner el código que tengas y que podamos ver el error (crea un [mcve]).

Answer (score 0):

prueba asignandole z-index a ambas pantallas y con números altos.

Ejem:

- Al contenedor del modal un z-index: 9
- Al contenedor del datepicker un z-index: 99.

EDITADO:

He replicado lo que has mencionado arriba usando:

- http://www.daterangepicker.com/
- Bootstrap 4

Creo que tu problema es el orden en el cual añades las referencias a los plugins. De cualquier forma aquí está el código funcionando. También lo puse en JS BIN : https://jsbin.com/qulomex/edit?html,output

```js
$(function() {

  var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
  var end = moment();

  function cb(start, end) {
    $('.reportrange span').html(start.format('YYYY MM DD') + ' - ' + end.format('YYYY MM DD'));
  }

  $('.reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
  }, cb);

  cb(start, end);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <a type="button" class="hvr-shutter-in-vertical filtradobtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
      BOTON
    </a>
  </div>



  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">SELECCIONAR</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="reportrange" name="reportrange" class="pull-right" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%;">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
            <span id="txt"></span> <b class="caret"></b>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn1" type="button">Aceptar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Eso no funciona, lo he intentado con propiedades altas de 10000 y  -10000 etc!

Comment: Puedes añadir en tu código el cdn del js y css que estás utilizando?

Comment: No hay codigos adicionales de ccs ni js adicionales a los publicados!

Comment: Oka, me refería a los plugins que estás utilizando, deberías saber que mencionando sólo el nombre no es una buena forma de encontrar el plugin que usas y así poder ayudarte en tu problema, de cualquier forma acabo de EDITAR mi respuesta, he añadido un codigo en JS Bin usando http://www.daterangepicker.com/ y el boostrap tradicional.